# Dotted Lines Around Questions?

Tags: support, sidebar

I see these dotted lines every once in a while: what do they mean?
[image]

Comment: Means Server Fault has some crufty styles

Comment: This question does not apply to MSO. It should be migrated to MSE or Meta Server Fault. In fact, I was confused trying to understand why you were seeing that if I couldn't see

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Those lines indicate the presence of an accepted answer on the question.

Different sites use different stylings for this. On many sites, the difference is imperceptible.

Opinions differ as to the usefulness of this indicator.

Comment: What are the different opinions as to its usefulness?

Comment: @smci: some find it useful, and some don't.